# Does Origen support register aliases?

Tags: origen-sdk

Can you add an alias to a register in Origen?  Like something similar to how the pin alias works?

```
dut.add_reg_alias :orig_reg, :new_reg
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not supported at the time of writing, although it should be.

In the meantime, you can work around by doing this:

```ruby
# Define the reg as you normally would with a default name
add_reg :reg1, 0x0 do |reg|
  # Bit definitions here
end

# Add an alias method for it like this
def reg1_alias; reg1 end
```

This will allow you to access it via the direct name, rather than via the reg() method (I would always recommend to use the direct name anyway).

```ruby
dut.reg1 == dut.reg1_alias  # => true
```